# Rationalize the denominator: $(\frac{3}{2x^2}) ^{1/4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My answer is $\frac{(6x^2)^{1/4}}{ 2x^2}$

However the book's answer is $\frac{(24x^2)^{1/4}}{2x}$

Where did the book get that from?

---

Here's my work: 
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{2x^2}}= \frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}}{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt[4]{6x^2}}{2x^2}$$

Since the product of two roots with the same index is the root of the product:
$$\sqrt[N]{a} \cdot \sqrt[N]{b} = \sqrt[N]{ab}$$

Comment: the last statement is correct, but the product of denominators isn't.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: yes. $\sqrt[4]{2x^2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{2x^2} = \sqrt[4]{2x^2 \cdot 2x^2} = \sqrt[2] {2x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Your error is when you go from the first line to the second.  We have
$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{2x^2}}= \frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}}{\sqrt[4]{2x^2}} = \frac{\sqrt[4]{6x^2}}{\sqrt[4]{4x^4}}$$

You can re-express the denominator as $\sqrt[4]{4}\sqrt[4]{x^4} = |x|\sqrt[4]{4}$, which is almost free of radicals (see my note below for where the absolute value came from).  Can you take it from here?

---

Looking at your work, you seem to be using the (erroneous) rule $\sqrt[N]{a} \cdot \sqrt[N]{a} = a$.  This is true for $N=2$, but not otherwise (this problem has $N=4$).

---

**Edit:** Technically, $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = x$ only holds if $x \ge 0$; the more general solution is $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = |x|$, since $\sqrt[4]{\cdot} \ge 0$.  You may have been given that $x>0$ for the problem, at which point $|x| = x$ and there is no difference, but it's a good idea to keep this fact in mind.

Comment: You multiplied the denominator by the same radical. Why hasn't the radicand been removed from the radical?

Comment: Remember that $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x}$ is the operation which 'undoes' $g(x) = x^n$ (in more technical language, the inverse).  Thus, to undo the radical $\sqrt[n]{\; }$, we have to raise it to the $n$-th power.  For $n=2$, this the same as multiplying by the same radical, but we have $n=4$, so we would have to multiply the the radical $3$ times (since we have $1$ radical, so multiplying by $3$ more will give use the fourth power, reversing the $\sqrt[4]{\; }$.  This is another valid way to solve the problem, although you'll have to simplify to get to the book's answer if you do that.

Comment: Can you explain in a different way?

Comment: Here's a concrete, numerical example:  $\sqrt[4]{2} = 1.892\ldots$.  $\sqrt[4]{2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{2} = 1.414\ldots\not= 2$.  But, $\sqrt[4]{2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{2} = 2$.  Notice we had to multiply four times to get rid of the $\sqrt[4]{\; }$.  Does that help?

Comment: Also, are you sure the book's answer wasn't $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{24x^2}}{2x}?$$

Comment: You are correct. That is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to multiply numerator and denominator by $(2x^2)^{\color{red}3/4}$, just because $\frac34+\frac14=1$:
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac3{2x^2}\biggr)^{1/4}&=\frac{3^{1/4}}{(2x^2)^{1/4}}=\frac{3^{1/4}(2x^2)^{3/4}}{2x^2}=\frac{(3\cdot8x^6)^{1/4}}{2x^2}\\
&=\frac{(24x^2)^{1/4}\cdot x}{2x^2}=\frac{\Bigl(\cfrac32x^2\Bigr)^{1/4}}x.
\end{align*}

Comment: The book states the answer is $\left(\frac{24x^2}{2x}\right)^{1/4}$

Comment: It's the same as what I wrote: $24=\dfrac32\cdot 16$ and $16^{1/4}=2$, which simplifies with 2 in denominator.

Comment: It would be more instructional for me as well as others if you explained why rationalizing the denominator with a root other than a square root does not eliminate the root in the same way as a square root.

Comment: @Cetshwayo: I updated my answer: is that clearer now?

Comment: May be you can show that you are multiplying the numerator and denominator by $(2x^2)^{\color{red}3/4}$. However, I follow what you did. Thanks so much.

Comment: Since I wrote it, I didn't think it was useful to show it :o)